# Why does the useEffect depending on the socket not have access to the updated state on the first re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 useEffect's in my React component. One of them (#1) has an empty dependency array and is responsible for fetching a list from my API. Thereafter, state is updated and the FlatList re renders perfectly. The other useEffect (#2) hook depends on a socket which emits any new items that have been added to the list from my API. However, this useEffect seems to have no idea that the state has been updated so when I try to use state and append the newly emitted item I only get back the new item. Adding further new items works fine since on the 2nd re-render, useEffect #2 has access to the updated state which contains the list from my API.

Example:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${getItemsUrl}`)
            //component re renders and all items are displayed. Thereafter, itemAdded event is emitted whenever a new item is added. 
            setItems(response.data)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.response.data)
        }
    })()
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    function handleItemAdded(newItem) {
        //Problem: items will be empty when the first newItem is received from the socket even though setItems was called in useEffect #1 and those initial items were already rendered on screen in a FlatList. As such, component re renders and only newItem is displayed.  
        setItems([newItem, ...items])
    }
    socket.on('itemAdded', handleItemAdded)
    return () => {
        socket.off('itemAdded', handleItemAdded)
    }
}, [socket])
```

Comment: Try using the function parameter version of setItems in your second useEffect, ie `setItems(items => [newItem, …items])`

Comment: As @James said when you use it as a callback it will get the most recent state https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state.